# url routing webforms conflict

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, url-routing

Im just getting into Global.asax and the way to do url routing in WebForms. Here Im having a bit of a conflict with my default.aspx and my other files.

I want all my files to have the friendly url ie. mysite.com/welcome/ etc and Im achieving this by doing:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("root_pages", "{file}/{*action}", "~/{file}.aspx");
```

by this I can write mysite.com/welcome.aspx into mysite.com/welcome/ and have a default action if I want. But then my conflict occurs between my default routing:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("default", "{*action}", "~/default.aspx");
```

I also want to access some action on my default.aspx - but it seems I cant when Im doing it like this?

It will pick the file line and go with that, so I cant do mysite.com/logout/ which is a function on my default.aspx page, it will ofcouse look for a file in this case.. Is there any other way to do what I want? So I can use both routes?

Hope you can help me out

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

It will always take the first route and go with it. In your case, it will look for logout.aspx which doesn't exist. The only option is to use the URL mysite.com/default/logout.

We can consider this as a limitation of URL Routing in WebForms.

You can check my blog series for URL Routing in Web forms at following URL.

http://karmic-development.blogspot.in/2013/10/url-routing-in-aspnet-web-forms-part-1.html

http://karmic-development.blogspot.in/2013/10/url-routing-in-aspnet-web-forms-part-2.html

There are more articles in this series.